# Integration over the intersection of the $n$-ball and a hyperplane

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let the $n$-ball of radius $r$, centred at $\mathbf{x}_0$, which will be denoted as the region 
$$
U = \{\mathbf{x}\in\Bbb{R}^n\colon\|\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0\|^2\leq r^2\},
$$
and is shown in the figure below. Also let a function $f\colon\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{R}$ defined as
$$
f(\mathbf{x}) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  c  & \mbox{if } \mathbf{x}\in U \\
  0  & \mbox{if } \mathbf{x}\notin U.
 \end{array}
\right.
$$
We would like to evaluate the following integral
$$
I=
\int_{\Omega}\!
\Big[\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{x}+b\Big]f(\mathbf{x})
\,\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x},
$$
where the region $\Omega$ is defined as the halfspace 
$$
\Omega = \{\mathbf{x}\in\Bbb{R}^n\colon\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{x}+b\geq0\}.
$$
Apparently, this is equal (does this really hold?) to the following:
$$
I=
\int_{\Omega\cap U}\!
c\Big[\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{x}+b\Big]
\,\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}.
$$

Any ideas on how to evaluate this integral in terms of $\mathbf{a}$, $b$, and $c$?

Thank you in advance.

[image: $n$-ball & hyperplane intersection]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**: First of all, rotate the picture so that $a=(0,0,\dots,0,1)$. Then you'll be integrating $$\int_{U\cap\{x_n+b\ge 0\}} c(x_n+b)\,d\mathbf x.$$
Do this as a single integral, slicing with hyperplanes $x_n=\text{constant}$. It will help to let $\gamma$ represent the volume of the unit ball in $\Bbb R^{n-1}$.

More specifically, we can move $\mathbf x_0$ to the origin, by appropriately adjusting the constant $b$. So it suffices to consider $\Omega = \{\mathbf x\in\Bbb R^n: \|\mathbf x\|\le r, a\le x_n\}$. Then
$$\int_\Omega c(x_n+b)d\mathbf x = \int_a^r c(t+b)(r^2-t^2)^{(n-1)/2}\gamma\,dt,$$
since the cross-section of $\Omega$ when $x_n=t$ is a $(n-1)$-dimensional ball of radius $\sqrt{r^2-t^2}$.

Comment: Dear Mr. Ted Shifrin, first, many thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I cannot follow your approach exactly... Could you elaborate more?

Comment: Thank you very much for your approach. Would you give me some help on the integral $\int_{a}^{r}\big(r^2-t^2\big)^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\mathrm{d}t$? Where should I look for? I understand that Gamma or Beta function may appear, but what confuse me are the limits of the integral in such a case! Appreciate your help!

Comment: Well, if $n$ is odd, this is a polynomial integral. I don't know offhand what the simplest form for the answer is. If $n$ is even, you want to use a trig substitution. Gamma functions appear in $\gamma$ :P

Comment: @nullgeppetto: What I said in chat had a small error. If you make the trig substitution $t=r\cos\theta$, then your integral becomes $r^n\displaystyle\int_0^{\arccos(a/r)} \sin^{(n+1)/2}\theta\,d\theta$.